# Taking just two decimals without rounding it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically,  I have a list of float numbers with too many decimals. So when I created a second list with two decimals, Python rounded them. I used the following:

```
g1= ["%.2f" % i for i in g]
```

Where g1 is the new list with two decimals, but rounded, and g is the list with float numbers.

How can I make one without rounding them?
I'm a newbie, btw. Thanks!

Comment: `g1 = [x * 100 // 1 / 100 for x in g0]`

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to truncate the numbers at the second digit?
Beware that rounding might be the better and more accurate solution anyway.

If you want to truncate the numbers, there are a couple of ways - one of them is to multiply the number by 10 elevated to the number of desired decimal places (100 for 2 places), apply "math.floor", and divide the total back by the same number.

However, as internal floating point arithmetic is not base 10, you'd risk getting more decimal places on the division to scale down.

Another way is to create a string with 3 digits after the "." and drop the last one - that'd be rounding proof.

And again, keep in mind that this converts the numbers to strings - what should be done for presentation purposes only. Also, "%" formatting is quite an old way to format parameters in a string. In modern Python, f-strings are the preferred way:

```
g1 = [f"{number:.03f}"[:-1] for number in g]
```

Another, more correct way, is, of course, treat numbers as numbers, and not play tricks on adding or removing digits on it. As noted in the comments, the method above would work for numbers like "1.227", that would be kept as "1.22", but not for "2.99999", which would be rounded to "3.000" and then truncated to "3.00". 
Python has the `decimal` modules, which allows for arbitrary precision of decimal numbers - which includes less precision, if needed, and control of the way Python does the rounding - including rounding towards zero, instead of the nearest number.

Just set the decimal context to the `decimal.ROUND_DOWN` strategy, and then convert your numbers using either the `round` built-in (the exact number of digits is guaranteed, unlike using round with floating point numbers), or just do the rounding as part of the string formatting anyway. You can also convert your floats do Decimals in the same step:

```
from decimals import Decimal as D, getcontext, ROUND_DOWN

getcontext().rounding = ROUND_DOWN

g1 = [f"{D(number):.02f}" for number in g]
```

Again - by doing this, you could as well keep your numbers as Decimal objects, and still be able to perform math operations on them:

```
g2 = [round(D(number, 2)) for number in g]
```

Comment: `2.99999` would still round to `3.00` with this method, not truncate to `2.99`.

Comment: Thanks - I will update the answer to reflect this, Meanwhile, the proper way to go, using decimal.Decimal actually works.

Comment: Thank you so much! Well, I'm considering using truncated numbers because I'm reporting standard error in my lab of mechanics.

Comment: Did you try negative numbers?  -2.99999 return -3.00 with ROUND_FLOOR.  `f'{int(num*100)/100:.02f}'` works.

Comment: I first used decimal with the ` ROUND_FLOOR` strategy, and that does not work for negative nubmers (as -3.00 is the "floor" for -2.99) - but I subsequently updted the answer to use ROUND_DOWN, which will always round towards zero.

Comment: @ClaraGarcía: "Well, I'm considering using truncated numbers because I'm reporting standard error in my lab of mechanics." - I'm pretty sure standard practice is to round for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution where we don't even need to convert the number's to string to get the desired output:

```
def format_till_2_decimal(num):
    return int(num*100)/100.0


g = [-5.427926, -12.222018, 7.214379, -16.771845, -6.1441464, 10.1383295, 14.740516, 5.9209185, -9.740783, -10.098338]

formatted_g = [format_till_2_decimal(num) for num in g]
print(formatted_g)
```

Hope this solution helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Here might be the answer you are looking for:

```py
g = [-5.427926, -12.222018, 7.214379, -16.771845, -6.1441464, 10.1383295, 14.740516, 5.9209185, -9.740783, -10.098338]

def trunc(number, ndigits=2):
    parts = str(number).split('.') # divides number into 2 parts. for ex: -5, and 4427926 
    truncated_number = '.'.join([parts[0], parts[1][:ndigits]]) # We keep this first part, while taking only 2 digits from the second part. Then we concat it together to get '-5.44'
    return round(float(truncated_number), 2)  # This should return a float number, but to make sure it is roundded to 2 decimals. 

g1 = [trunc(i) for i in g]
print(g1)
[-5.42, -12.22, 7.21, -16.77, -6.14, 10.13, 14.74, 5.92, -9.74, -10.09]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that was what I did first. I want, instead of -5.43, -5.42.

Comment: I got what you meant, please check out the edited answer :)

Comment: do my answer address your question? :D

Comment: As I put in my answer - treating numbers as string s in not usually the best choice for dealing with numbers at all - and even more when there are tools that can do this keeping numbers as numbers.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Thanks! I can see you transformed the initial float number to a string one and then did the opposite. But how does the part truncated_number works?

Comment: thanks for pointing it. I think the same effect with string formatting in python to this problem. As I look for the decimal package, it also treats numbers as string.

Comment: I'll put more comments in the code, please check @ClaraGarcía

Comment: I just read your comment, @jsbueno is helping me to understand why I can do those movements. Really, I'm learning and I can tell lots of these explanations are not as clear as they must for me.

Comment: I think @jsbueno give very well-detailed explanation that you might spend time to read and got it. Enjoy your learning.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if David's answer is what you are looking for, it can be done simply as following:

```
g = [-5.427926, -12.222018, 7.214379, -16.771845, -6.1441464, 10.1383295, 14.740516, 5.9209185, -9.740783, -10.098338]

g1 = [("%.3f" % i)[:-1] for i in g]
```

Just take 3 decimals, and remove the last chars from the result strings. (You may convert the result to float if you like)

Comment: Yeah! The easiest way! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! But keep in mind there are edge cases of continuous carry. For example `("%.3f" % 9.99999)[:-1]`